# Error while creating embedding vector (for matrices) (Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create embedding vector for matrices.

first I'm converting the input of matrices to vector:

```
x = input_x.reshape(input_x.shape[0], input_x.shape[1]*input_x.shape[2])
```

i.e each sample (each input) is vector (instead of matrix)

And I'm building the following model:

```
max_length = x.shape[0]   # number of rows / number of samples
Vocab_size = 200
num_labels = 3 
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=Vocab_size, output_dim=8, input_length=max_length)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, verbose=0)
```

- The x.shape (after reshape) = (574, 80000)
- y.shape is 574

But I'm getting error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4592 but received input with shape [None, 640000]
```

full error:

```
  /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:985 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:372 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:386 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:508 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    /home/user/myPrj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))
```

- What is wrong ?
- what do I need to change in order to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the argument `max_length` wrong:

> **input_length**: Length of input sequences, when it is constant. This argument is required if you are going to connect Flatten then Dense layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be computed).

It should be

```
max_length=x.shape[-1]
```

Also, `input_dim` should be

> **input_dim**: Integer. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.

I don't understand your reshaping operation, you might have made a mistake there too.

Answer (score 0):

Input of your model should have last dimension of 200.

As far as I understand the last dimension of input_x is 200 (Vocab_size). If so - try to reshape this way:

```
x = input_x.reshape(-1, input_x.shape[-1])
```